# Strange behaviour of threading python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a certain code I want to parallelize using threads in python. The function is :

```
def sanity(url):
    global count
    count+=1
    if count%1000==0:
       print(count)
    try:
       if 'media' in url[:10]:
           url = "http://dummy.s3.amazonaws.com" + url
       req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"})
       ret = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
       all_urls.append(url)
       return 1
except (urllib.request.HTTPError,urllib.request.URLError,http.client.HTTPException, ValueError) as e:
    print(e, url)
    allurls.append(url)
    errors.append(url)
    return 0
```

I have a list of urls for which I have to run the above function for each url. So, I used threading. The code is given below:

```
 start=0
 arr=[0,1000,2000,...15000]
 for i in arr:
     threads = [threading.Thread(target=sanity, args=(url, errors,allurls,)) for url in urls[start:i]]
     [thread.start() for thread in threads]
     [thread.join() for thread in threads]
     if i==0:
        start=0
     else:
        start=i+1
```

The above code uses threading in python to run the function parallely on all the urls. However, the results returned vary every time and don't match with the results of serial version. What could be the problem?

Any help is appreciated!.

Comment: Starting 1000 threads at a time could easily exceed your network or OS imposed threading limits. I'd strongly recommend using `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` instead of manually created threads.

Comment: You won't get more threads using `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` as it still uses the underlying OS. if you need this amount of parallelism and expect long delays, the best bet is probably to use an asynchronous approach.

Comment: @JohanL: To be clear, I wasn't suggesting the `Pool` as a means to get more threads. I was suggesting it as a means to parallelize by work splitting among many (but less than one per task) worker threads. You're rarely able to do just about anything with 1000 parallel threads, but splitting 1000 work items among, say, 32 threads, works fine, and with similar performance.

Answer (score 0):

I would limit your use of parallelization to the I/O-bound calls to `urllib.request.urlopen`. One benefit is not having to deal with globals or thread-local objects.

The example below uses [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html). It is written as a stand-alone module that could easily accept `argparse` inputs e.g. your list of URLs. You could also encapsulate the `ThreadPoolExecutor` in a function.

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
import urllib

def sanity(url):
    """Attempt an HTML request"""
   if 'media' in url[:10]:
       url = "http://dummy.s3.amazonaws.com" + url
   req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"})
   ret = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
   return ret

URLS = ('collection', 'of', 'strings')
allurls = []
errors = []

# set `max_workers` to your preferred upper limit of threads
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    pool = {executor.submit(sanity, url): url for url in URLS}

    # perform error handling as each future completes
    for future in as_completed(pool):
        res = future.result()
        if isinstance(res, (urllib.request.HTTPError, urllib.request.URLError,
                      http.client.HTTPException, ValueError)):
            print(res, pool[res])
            # append the URL to lists as appropriate
            allurls.append(pool[res])
            errors.append(pool[res])
        else:
            allurls.append(pool[res])

# do something with `allurls` and `errors`
```